# How to relate Customer and Payment Details

Tags: c#, java, oop

I have a query related to relation between objects.

Scenario:

Payment Details - 
a. Credit Card
b. Saving Account
c. Cheque

Now, a customer should have any of the above payment detail before buying any product. How do i relate payment detail with customer.

Can any one explain with example...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are aware that the payment details should probably be linked to a transaction/invoice, as the same customer might have multiple payments, or pay the same invoice in multple partial ways.

Comment: Correct, My concern is how to relate payment details with a transaction or invoice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface IPaymentType 
{
  bool Pay(double amount);
}

public class CreditCardPType : IPaymentType
{
  double limit;
  // implement Pay()
}    
public class Cheque: IPaymentType
{
  int accountNumber;
  // implement Pay()
} 

public class Customer
{
    public IPaymentType paymentType { get; set; }
}


Customer customer = new Customer();
customer.paymentType = new CreditCardPType();
```

Comment: This good for Credit Card Payment Type, what else in case of cheque. Both Credit Card and Cheque have few different attributes.

Comment: derive the other two classes from IPaymentType interface

Comment: define behaviour like Pay() or something in interface. Keep attributes seperate to your classes. Have made editions

Comment: But our interface has only the common attributes for both and Customer and Payment Type is related through interface. so i am not able to get all the attributes of Cheque.

Comment: why are you putting attributes in interface ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get your question correctly, may be you can have a *Customer* class which has an attribtute "modeOfPayment" and this can be any of the possible options. Initialize this attribute in the constructor of the *Customer* class.

Alternatively may be keeping the payment details in a class like "Order" might be a better option. A customer can choose to pay for an order using credit card (say) and for some he can choose to pay by other means.

Answer (score 0):

Add a Payment Detail property\field to your Customer Object. This will be the default payment mode when a customer buys a product.